# Gerrit get diff between 2 commits

Tags: gerrit

I want to get diff between two commits using Gerrit Rest API https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html
I found the Get Diff API in Gerrit document but it's not what I need. I want something like using git diff.

Can anyone help me?